# Warp sarama-cluster consuming action in a goroutine, then it fails to consume anything

Tags: go, kafka-consumer-api, sarama

I'm using `sarama-cluster` lib to create a kafka group consumer, in a backend service. This example code from [godoc](https://godoc.org/github.com/bsm/sarama-cluster#example-Consumer) works:

```golang
for {
    if msg, ok := <-consumer.Messages(); ok {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "%s/%d/%d\t%s\t%s\n", msg.Topic, msg.Partition, msg.Offset, msg.Key, msg.Value)
        consumer.MarkOffset(msg, "") // mark message as processed
    }
}
```

since it's a dead loop, I put it in a goroutine to avoid blocking other activities, then it can no longer consume any message:

```golang
go func() {
    for msg := range consumer.Messages() {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "%s/%d/%d\t%s\t%s\n", msg.Topic, msg.Partition, msg.Offset, msg.Key, msg.Value)
        consumer.MarkOffset(msg, "") // mark message as processed
    }
}()
```

(service is running, so this goroutine is not terminated. It just fails to consume)

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Do you close the channel after firing up the for loop?

Comment: @rsp I think no, the channel is owned by the lib, I just call `Messages()` to read from it.

Comment: You're not meant to close this channel, in fact you can't because it's a read only channel - you can't send on it and you can't close it. What @rsp is probably referring to is if you've closed it then the loop (and the goroutine) would exit immediately. Double check if this goroutine and loop is running.

Comment: @Patryk Yes. Above the message reading, there is a `defer consumer.Close()` statement. So wrapping consuming action in goroutine makes the function exit quickly. My carelessness!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sarama-cluster` is in unmaintained for quite some time already [with the following notice](https://github.com/bsm/sarama-cluster#deprecation-notice):

> Please note that since https://github.com/Shopify/sarama/pull/1099 was
>   merged and released (>= v1.19.0) this library is officially
>   deprecated. The native implementation supports a variety of use cases
>   that are not available through this library.

I suggesty you to use [github.com/Shopify/sarama](https://github.com/Shopify/sarama) instead. It has all the functionalities of `sarama-cluster` and it's actively maintained.

You can follow a simple consumer group example [from their repository](https://github.com/Shopify/sarama/blob/master/examples/consumergroup/main.go).

Comment: Helpful reference! Yet I still haven't figured out why the two versions in my question behave differently~

Comment: Solved. As comments under the question suggest, channel closed (by  a `defer consumer.Close()`) after firing up the for loop...

Comment: @June Glad you figured it out!